# Is there a way to prevent self-deletion of the superuser user in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to restrict the self-deletion of super users in django admin (maintaining the ability to edit):

1. If trying to self-delete it should result in a validation error
2. Super user must maintain the ability to remove other users, so `has_delete_permission()` is not an option for me.

I have tried using signals:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def delete_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instance.is_superuser:
         raisePermissionDenied
```

but, it results in HTTP status 403 and not Validation Error.

Now I am trying using a custom user admin, where I have tried several methods (override save method, override form), but probably due to my inexperience with django I don't know if this approach is correct. So I turn to those who can help me.

Thank you so much

Comment: Why not just have a `delete(request, user_id)` view and validate in the form's `clean` method or the view that the user isn't deleting themselves, or if they are a superuser